# Trying to get width of element inside .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, offsetwidth

I am trying to get the width of an element whilst inside a .each() function however I am running into issues with it simply not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.tooltip').each(function() {
        var self = $(this);

        var width = self.find("#testing").offsetWidth;
        alert(width); //Returns undefined

        $(this).find(".tooltip-icon").hover(function(){
            self.find(".tooltip-text").show();
        }, function () {
            self.find(".tooltip-text").hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: [`self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) js native variable

Comment: Please note that according to your logic you have multiple elements with the id `testing`, And an ID should always be unique

Comment: I am aware of self and also aware of IDs being unique, changing to a class does not fix the problem this is purely something I put together for testing hence the name testing.

Comment: @DanielVickers Please include your html, that will give us a better chance of solving your problem

Comment: No need for HTML, was all correct. I knew it was relational to purely this jquery/js and was confident that the person who knew what was wrong would not need the HTML ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using jquery and javascript in the same line

do this

```
var width = self.find("#testing").width(); // jquery. you should change the name of the `self` variable to another one
```

Comment: The jQuery option worked, however, please note that the javascript method does not as it returns the same error mentioned in my question. Will accept once able to.

Comment: @DanielVickers Yes i forget that `self` is a jquery variable so the second way will not work